# Best practice to use Entity Framework interceptors in App.config/Web.config while migration

Tags: entity-framework, logging, migration, nlog

I use Entity Framework interceptor in my Web.config to log database changes:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <interceptors>
      <interceptor type="SomeNamespace.EFCommandInterceptor, MyDatabaseProjectInSolution">
      </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
  </entityFramework>
```

EFCommandInterceptor calls another logger, which is a wrapper over NLog.

An error occurs when I try to migrate a database. Null reference exception happens in the specified Logger which is called from SomeNamespace.EFCommandInterceptor.

When I remove interceptors from Web.config - everything is ok. But it seems to me, it is not good practice to remove piece of code every time when you need to migrate database

Here are logger classes:

```
public  static class LoggerFactory
    {
        public static LoggerWrapper Logger { get; } =  new LoggerWrapper();
    }

public class LoggerWrapper
    {

        private readonly NLog.Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public void Log(LoggerLevel logLevel, string project, string @class, string message)
        {
            var res= new StringBuilder();

            var login = HttpContext.Current.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "User is not authentificated";

            res.Append($"{login,-30}");
            res.Append("|");
            res.Append($"{project,-10}");
            res.Append("|");
            res.Append($"{@class,-30}");
            res.Append("|");
            res.Append(message);

            LogLevel level;

            switch (logLevel)
            {
                case LoggerLevel.Trace:
                    level=LogLevel.Trace;
                    break;
                case LoggerLevel.Debug:
                    level = LogLevel.Debug;
                    break;
                case LoggerLevel.Info:
                    level=LogLevel.Info;
                    break;
                case LoggerLevel.Warn:
                    level=LogLevel.Warn;
                    break;
                case LoggerLevel.Error:
                    level=LogLevel.Error;
                    break;
                default: 
                    level=LogLevel.Info;
                    break;
            }

            logger.Log(level,res.ToString());
        }
    }

public class EFCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
    {

        public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("NonQueryExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("NonQueryExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ReaderExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ReaderExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ReaderExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<System.Data.Common.DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ReaderExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ScalarExecuted", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        public void ScalarExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            LogInfo("ScalarExecuting", String.Format(" IsAsync: {0}, Command Text: {1}", interceptionContext.IsAsync, command.CommandText));
        }

        private void LogInfo(string command, string commandText)
        {
            LoggerFactory.Logger.Log(LoggerLevel.Info, nameof(DatabaseProject), "DATABASE", $"command: {command} text: {commandText}" );
        }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `HttpContext.Current.User?.Identity?.Name` to `HttpContext?.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name`

Comment: Rolf, you were close to the right answer. The problem was in the EFCommandInterceptor. After I changed code LoggerFactory.Logger.Log... to LoggerFactory.Logger?.Log... the program worked without errors. It seems to me, that the reason is that Logger is situated in the Extensions project, but Entity Framework is situated in DAL project. When the migration starts, it runs only DAL project, so LoggerFactory.Logger==null in case of running add-migration command in Package Manager

Comment: So. In case of working with migrations, you should either move your logger into project where migrations are situated or make your code skip logging when migration starts